# addEventListener behavior on Safari with `click` event - not working properly

Tags: javascript, safari

The `fx_Hello` function when called inside the `addEventListener` with the "click" event, returns an alert PopUp to appear whenever I click on any part of the HTML page or Elements of the page. In **Chrome** and **Mozzila** browsers it's working perfectly, but in **Safari** browser for IOS, the PopUp is only appearing if you click on the link with the id `some_ID`.

Can anyone tell me why `addEventListener` behavior in Safari is not the same as in other browsers?

How can I make it work in Safari?

**HTML Page:**

```
<body>
 <div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="some_ID">Click Here</a>
 </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var vMain = {
 
 fx_Hello(e){ 
  alert("Hello World!");
  console.log("id: " + e.target.parentNode.id);
 },

 fx_Goodbye(e){ 
  alert("Goodbye Cruel World!");
  console.log("id: " + e.target.parentNode.id); 
 }

}

window.addEventListener("click", function (){ 
 vMain.fx_Hello(event);
});
```

**try here:** https://jsfiddle.net/ivorubim_code/jLb8uyqs/2/

Comment: [Many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=safari+ios+click+anywhere+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

start an `addEventListener` with as event `touchstart`.

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){ 
 vMain.fx_Hello(event);
});
```

**try here:** https://jsfiddle.net/ivorubim_code/jLb8uyqs/3/